# Why session based authentication is no longer best practice?

Tags: web, session-cookies, access-token

I have been hearing that because of the explosion of mobile internet that session based authentication is already dead. Now web development is now using token-based authentication.

Can someone explain what are the problems of session and cookie based authentication that led to this change and also how token based authentication solves the problems ?

Comment: I can't see how session base authentication is dead, still seems pretty prevalent to me

Comment: @m.edmondson Yeah but when would you choose token based authentication over session-cookie based authentication and why ?

Comment: My understanding of token based authentication is a server provided token being based to the server (on each request).  Is this not the same as session-based authentication (i.e. the token is within the cookie).

Comment: @m.edmondson Yes but why would you use a token instead of the normal cookie based authentication ? See if there was never a problem with session based authentication no one would ever use anything else. But now token based authentication is slowly gaining popularity. My question is why ? That means there must be some shortcomings of the former method that is solved by the later method. What are those ?

Comment: My viewpoint is that I'm dubious there is a difference between the two

Comment: @m.edmondson But that doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 6):

The problem of cookie based authentication is caused by the mechanism of how cookies work. Cons of a cookie based authentication are as blow:

1. CORS. cookies + CORS don't play well across different domains.
2. CSRF. you need to prevent your api from CSRF attack.
3. Mobile platform. cookies is for web browser. You need to do extra work for mobile native platform which is hard to implement.

For more detail of this topic. The follow link is where you want to go [Cookies vs Tokens. Getting auth right with Angular.JS](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am critic of Session based authentication as well coz it affects scalability and does not fit anywhere with trend of serverless or stateless computing with Lambda and Beanstalk kinda services we are heading towards. Already a great answer is here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/92123